# Include java dependencies in search

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to include the java dependencies of a project to the search for a text / class in vs code? Currently only my project is included but not the libraries that are added through maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its possible by using Quick Open (Ctrl+P) then enter the '#' command to search the current workspace (which includes the java dependencies). Ctrl+T works as well which is the shortcut for the '#'.